# How do I fix these weird lines in my model

Tags: modeling, mesh

I was following along with Darrin Liles character modeling tutorial, and I was doing well, but then I left edit mode and turned off wireframe. I got lines like this (by nose and jaw):

[image: Line proof]

I have no idea how to fix this. Help?

Here's the .blend file:

[image]

Comment: Hi and welcome to BlenderSE. Please use http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/ to provide .blend files for analysis. Links to other services often get invalid after a while because people might delete their files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those lines are a result of mesh distortion. It means that your polygons aren't "flat". Mesh distortion results in shading errors.

Blender's Mesh Analysis functionality helps you checking with these kind of problems. In the screenshot below you see all the distorted polygons in your mesh. Grey is ok, then it goes from blue to green and finally to red (which means bad).

[image: mesh analysis]

This is OK to a certain extend, but it depends on the purpose of your model. I would stay in the grey and blue-ish area to keep things safe.

The solution in your case would be working with a little more polygons, for example by adding loopcuts and then moving the vertices until the polygons change their color into blue or turquoise.

Comment: I can't seem tp get it to work in my version of blender

Comment: How did you get it to work?

Comment: @Ian - You have to deactivate the Mirror Modifier to get it working. Mesh Analysis also doesn't like Matcaps as well as several other modifiers.